# Blargs package isn't working

Tags: python

```
import blargs
from blargs import Parser

with Parser(locals()) as p:
    p.str('arg1')
```

Here's my command:

```
python2 temp.py --arg1 "hi"
```

Error:

```
illegal option -- arg1
usage: temp.py [--help,-h]
```

2nd error using python2 temp.py arg1 "hi":

```
python2 temp.py arg1 "hi"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 5, in <module>
    p.str('arg1')
AttributeError: 'Parser' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Here's pip info:

```
pip2 show blargs
Name: blargs
Version: 0.2.22a0
Summary: Blargs command line parser
Home-page: https://bitbucket.org/gyllstromk/blargs
Author: Karl Gyllstrom
Author-email: karl.gyllstrom+blargs@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blargs-0.2.22a0-py2.7.egg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `-arg1 "hi"` and `arg1 "hi"` produce similar results?

Comment: It was a different error, see the edit above.  Is it possible python2 is using a different version?  Or was the interface changed?  I'm on a Mac if that makes a difference.

Comment: I have tried this module on Mac myself and got the same results as you.  The doc does say that it is tested on 2.6, and I am on 2.7.  It also says that it works on 3.2, but using `pip3` it installs the python 2 version (fails on python 3 around bare `print` statements).

Comment: I noticed that `pip` installs `blargs-0.1.tar.gz` but on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blargs/0.2.29b there is a version 0.2.29b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` installs an old version: `blargs-0.1.tar.gz`.  Download a newer version from [github](https://github.com/gyllstromk/blargs)

- click on "Clone or Download" then "Download ZIP"
- copy the `blargs-master` directory from "downloads" to your home directory
- Remove the old module with `sudo pip uninstall blargs`
- `cd blargs-master`
- `sudo python setup.py install`
- run your test again

Tested on python 2.7 and 3.6 on Mac.

Comment: It seems you are right, I simply added the newest blargs.py to my script folder.  However, it's weird that pip2 show says version 0.2.22 ... any idea why that is?  Why is python2 looking in a different location than pip2?

Comment: I was looking into that myself and I don't have any idea.  It could be the weird paths that OS X uses for python, but I don't have a good explanation.  I have installed the "good" version now and don't really want to roll it back to look into it!